Split column depending on content
I have column similar to this:



Column A




spa:34,spd:76


spa:21


,spd:2


spa:99,spd:12



I would like to split the column and get this:



Column A
Column B




spa:34
spd:76


spa:21




spd:2


spa:99
spd:12



How can I achieve this in Power Query?
I know how to split a column with a delimiter but if the first value is missing in a cell the value gets placed in the wrong column.

If there is a single value in the cell, what is the logic to determine if the missing value is the first or the second value?

The column looks like the first table.
I need to split all "spa:x" to one column and all the "spd:x" to another column.

This should work and is a bit more generalized than what you describe. If you need exactly what you describe, that requires a small modification.

Find the first cell that has two entries.
Use that order to determine first vs second split

M Code (from advanced editor)
let

//Change next line to reflect actual table name or other data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    
//set data type to type text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column A", type text}}),
    
//Determine first vs second values
    #"First/Second" = 
        let

     //find cell with two entries
            both = List.Generate(
                ()=>[a=Text.Split(#"Changed Type"{0}[Column A],","),idx=0],
                each List.Count([a]) =2,
                each [a = Text.Split(#"Changed Type"{[idx]+1}[Column A],","), idx = [idx]+1],
                each List.RemoveItems([a],{""}))
        in 
            List.Transform(List.Last(both), each Text.Split(_,":"){0}),

    #"Add Splitted Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Splitted", (r)=> 
        if Text.Contains(r[Column A],",")
            then Record.FromList(Text.Split(r[Column A],","),{"Column A", "Column B"})
            else Record.FromList(
                    List.ReplaceRange(
                        {null,null}, 
                        List.PositionOf(#"First/Second",Text.Split(r[Column A],":"){0}),
                        1,
                        {r[Column A]}),
                    {"Column A","Column B"}),
            type [Column A=nullable text, Column B=nullable text]
            ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Splitted Column",{"Column A"}),
    #"Expanded Splitted" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Splitted", {"Column A","Column B"})
in
    #"Expanded Splitted"


If you want EXACTLY what you write handling only spa: and spd:, you can use the following code instead:
let

//Change next line to reflect actual table name or other data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    
//set data type to type text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column A", type text}}),

    #"Add Splitted Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Splitted", (r)=>
        let 
            split = Text.Split(r[Column A],","),
            spa = List.FindText(split,"spa:"){0}?,
            spd = List.FindText(split, "spd:"){0}?
        in [Column A = spa, Column B = spd],
            type [Column A=nullable text, Column B=nullable text]),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Splitted Column",{"Column A"}),
    #"Expanded Splitted" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Splitted", {"Column A", "Column B"})
in
    #"Expanded Splitted"


Just right click on the column and select Split Column, By Delimiter, and select comma as your delimiter.  If the comma is there, the column gets split correctly.
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column A.1", type text}, {"Column A.2", type text}})


